# Android Intent filter does not show my app

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, show

I added this in my manifest to give the user the ability to open a xml file with my app. But when i click on a xml file and say "open with..." my app does not show up in the list! I also removed and installed the app new! The name of the file I test with is Test.xml

```
 <activity
       android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
       android:label="mainAcitivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">

       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:scheme="file"
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"
            android:mimeType="*/*"  />
       </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the right schema doesn't work, so delete your data tags and try this:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/xml"/>
<data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
<data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
<data android:scheme="https" android:mimeType="text/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"/>
```

Let me know

Comment: <intent-filter android:label="string resource">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.oli"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.oli" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.oli" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.oli" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>

Comment: How can I check if the app was launched by the file?

Comment: Get the intent and parse the data

Answer (score 2):

Get the intent, and parse the data!